# SMS messages do not get deleted automatically out the Android device SMS inbox for Android version 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

SMS messages do not get deleted automatically out the Android device SMS inbox for Android version 4.4 while in other lower version it works fine.
As i got to know abortBroadcast() is not working in Kitkat version ,May i know any thing we can do so that we dont get sms in sms inbox and its notification in kitkat.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own SMS client and convince the user to switch to it.

As of Android 4.4, SMS is for the *user*, and so all SMS messages go to the user's chosen SMS client. Apps that previously had used SMS for a control channel should switch to something else, such as Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

Comment: I want to use only messaging , not any gcm ..is that any different way ??

Comment: @user3632140: No. Messaging is for users, not apps, as of Android 4.4.

Comment: Actually my messages gets remain in sms inbox in kitkat version but in other version it gets automatically delete..this issue i am facing when i am using sms-gateway not by gcm , i cant use any google account ...can any one tell me how to fix that

Comment: @user3632140: There is nothing to "fix". Everything is working as expected. More importantly, it is working [as documented](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

Comment: but i dont want sms in my inbox..abortBroadcast() do take care for that but in kitkat version it is not working.. is there any substitute for abortBroadcast() for whick kitkat supports

Comment: @user3632140: "but i dont want sms in my inbox" -- then do not use SMS. "is there any substitute for abortBroadcast()" -- no.

Comment: please check this :- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: @user3632140: I linked to that post earlier in this comment thread. Please feel free to read that post.

Comment: can i check the version , if kitkat version is there , then i can disable <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />can i do like that to resolve the issue

Comment: can i increase <intent-filter android:priority of reciever in manifest..is that way i can stop message..

Comment: @user3632140: No, that will not help. Please read the blog post that you linked to.

Comment: @CommonWare so plz can u tell ..how to stop that..i need to solve that..i am naive in android..plz help

Comment: Is there any way that my message will not remain in sms inbox in kitkat version..